# please help me about the grep usage in unix, cannot identify the lower/hyper case

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I want my shell can only find out the pattern in the quote,
but the result also returned something like `"MSGxxxxx"` 
Anybody who can give me some advise?

Here is my script:

```
if egrep -e 'Msg|duplicate|deadlock|status = -|terminated due to disconnect' MYFILE.log
 then
    echo "I found something in your RAW data."    
  else
    echo "Nothing found!"
fi
```

Comment: do you mean to ask why grep returned capital "MSG" when you have "Msg" in the expression?

Comment: Some sample input and expected output would clarify what you want.

Comment: Yes, a bit more information include a *partial* extract from MYFILE.log would help.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advise and help... haha....time flies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-w` flag in order to select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.

```
if egrep -w -e 'Msg|duplicate|deadlock|status = -|terminated due to disconnect' file
then
    echo "I found something in your RAW data."    
else
    echo "Nothing found!"
fi
```

Alternatively, use a word boundary `\b` as shown below:

```
if egrep -e '\bMsg\b|duplicate|deadlock|status = -|terminated due to disconnect' file
then
    echo "I found something in your RAW data."    
else
    echo "Nothing found!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pattern to match the end of line, use `$`. If you want it to match the beginning of line, use `^`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for grep's `-i` option to match case-insensitively.